# How to limit size of an array in Firestore on a write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know how to limit an array so new items get pushed in and old ones are discarded in the same write?

I'm guessing this isn't possible but it sure would be handy.

```js
                    // * Store notification
                    // Users collection
                    const usersCollection = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('notifications').doc();

                    // Write this notification to the database as well
                    await usersCollection.update({
                        count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment,
                        notifications: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                            'symbol': symbol,
                            'companyname': companyname,
                            'change': priceDifference,
                            'changeDirection': directionOperatorHandler,
                            'updatedPrice': symbolLatestPrice,
                            'timestamp': currentTimestamp,
                        })
                    });
```

*Written in Typescript*

---

Alternatively, I was thinking of running a scheduled cloud function every week to go through and trim down the arrays based on the timestamp.

The reason I'm using an array to store my notifications is because I'm expecting a lot of writes.

Comment: if you are running this from the client, you can make a security rule which looks for the value of count, also you can create a cloud function which is triggered on changes and keeps the counts value if you are on the server-side, you can implement this yourself with an if statement on the count value.

Comment: Thank you Andre, I will try what Doug suggested and if it doesn't meet my needs I will likely go with a scheduled cloud function 

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple configuration for this.  Your code should implement your requirements by:

1. Reading the document
2. Modifying the array in memory
3. Checking that the size is within limits
4. Writing the document back

Comment: Okay yeah duh I guess haha. At the cost of a read this seems like a good solution. Thanks again Doug!